Regarding Tokenizer of Hugging Face
Hard time understanding the working of tokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification,AutoTokenizer #hugging face libraries
tkz = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

The function
def tkz_func(x): return tkz(x['input'])

works perfectly when we apply it to the datasets, returns updated dataset with input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_masks
When we apply it to the dataframe df.apply(tkz_func,axis=1) it just returns the list of row names for all the row values
[input_ids,token_type_ids,attention_masks].
Why?
